# meta data on rows and columns in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large matrix of genetic data, individuals by SNPs, with values in 0, 1, 2.  Both individuals and SNPs have some associated meta data.  For example,

> individuals might have sex, ancestry, age, doctor, etc.
>   SNPs have chromosome, position, mutation type, etc.

The meta data is not hierarchical.  I want to organize this as a DataFrame so I can

1. easily filter on meta data values (e.g. age between 18 and 65)
2. still refer to the genetic data naturally by integer indices (e.g. df.iloc[0, 0] or df.values[0, 0] is the genotype of the first individual at the first SNP.)

Is this possible with Pandas?

What's the natural way to organize the data?

Comment: Hard to say without seeing some. Can you post, oh, five or ten representative lines? In some format we can copy-and-paste into a dataframe? (csv works)

Comment: Unless you post raw input data and what the desired output should look like this is too broad to answer

Comment: As a Data Warehouse architect, I beleive you are looking to make a 'data cube' out of your data. I would suggest you look into different open source data cube solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your level of expertise is based on the question, but I'd start by looking at the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html) on pandas `merge`.

It sounds like you have individuals as rows and SNPs as columns; I'll also assume that you have both data frames indexed by a unique identifier for each individual. If you have a second data frame with clinical data with the same index, you can combine them using the following line:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.merge(snp_df, clinical_df, how='inner', left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

That will give you only complete data; if you want to include individuals without clinical data, change the argument to `how=left` and that will keep every individual you have genetic data on.

To filter based on some information about the SNPs, I'd do something like this:

```
snp_info_dict = {...}  # Some information you already have, indexed by SNP
def test_function(single_snp_info):
    # Test something about the information, return True or False
good_snps = [snp for snp in snp_info_dict if test_function(snp_info_dict[snp])]
good_snps_df = df.loc[:, good_snps]
```

You might also do the above using operations on a pandas dataframe as well.